# Is there a way to get a random element out of a cursor in PL/PgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

I'm studying examples in PostgreSQL, and I can't find a way to get a single random element when dealing with a cursor.

I have seen many articles and documentation, but there seems to be no way to do it.The output would be a random number from the cursor, that is, a random element from the cursor.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "random element" do you mean a "random row" out of the cursor? Remember, that cursors are conceptually read one row at a time in the order the rows are produced.

Comment: Change your cursor query to `select num from client order by random()`

Comment: Or don't use a cursor and instead use a query that returns a single random value and assign it to a variable: `num1 := (select num from client order by random() limit 1);`

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a way to fetch a random row. We are not looking for a way to get a random value from inside the cursor, but from fetch.

Comment: "...I can't find a way to get a single random element when dealing with a cursor..." -- true. It's not possible to use a cursor in a non-sequential way. The answer is: you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a cursor. Instead, use a query that returns a single random value and assign it to a variable:

```
num1 := (select num from client order by random() limit 1);
```

Comment: Though correct, in a large table getting a random row can be quite expensive/slow.

Comment: I think I expressed myself wrong. The solution you propose is a valid solution for the example, but I am looking for a way to extract a random value from the cursor

Comment: @TheImpaler.  Selecting  all `num`  from `Client` and then running some form of random selection over that is not cheap either.

Comment: @galaxy31 you can't directly to that because the cursor has access to only the current row it's up to. The cursor doesn't even know how many rows are yet to come. You could get every row from a cursor and write them all to a table then run a query similar to this one over the data.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver True. The best solution I've seen so far is to make use of a serial identifier -- somehow enforce an ID to take serial values, let's say from 1 to 1 million -- and then just produce a random number in that range. Seeking the single row is very performant this way.

Comment: @TheImpaler I thought the same, however it would be brittle to gaps in the ID range, which can and do occur.

Answer (score 0):

A test case using a local table:

```
do $$
DECLARE 
    rec record;
    num1 integer;
    ct integer;
    cur1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT p_item_no FROM plant1;
    fetch_ct integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO ct count(*) from plant1;
    SELECT INTO fetch_ct (random() * ct)::integer;
    open cur1;
    fetch relative fetch_ct from cur1 into rec;
    num1 = rec.p_item_no;
    Raise Notice 'Num: %', num1;

close cur1;

end $$ 
Language 'plpgsql';

NOTICE:  Num: 2742
DO

--Running it again

NOTICE:  Num: 3083
DO
--And again
NOTICE:  Num: 4848
DO
```